# How to dynamically shape a DAG in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I have a custom DAG (meant to be subclassed), let's name it `MyDAG`. In the `__enter__` method I want to add (or not) an operator based on the subclassing DAG. I'm not interested in using the [`BranchPythonOperator`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_branch_operator.py).

```
class MyDAG(DAG):
    def __enter__(self, context):
         start = DummyOperator(taks_id=start)
         end = DummyOperator(task_id=end)
         op = self.get_additional_operator()

         if op:
            start >> op
         else:
             start >> end
         retrun self
     def get_additional_operator(self):
         # None if the subclass doesn't add any operator. A reference to another operator otherwise
```

if `get_additional_operator` is returning a reference, I'm obtaining this shape (two branches):

```
* start --> op
* end
```

otherwise, if it's returning `None`, I'm obtaining this (one branch):

```
* start --> end
```

What I want is not having `end` at all in the subclass inherting from `MyDAG` if `get_additional_operator` doesn't return `None`, something like this:

```
* start --> op
```

Instead of the two branches I'm obtaining above.

Comment: This goes against Airflow Best Practices as a DAG should not change shape over time. Reasons for this are that a DAGs structure is generated from the DAG file as it is rendered at the time. This means that having the structure shift will result in loss of ability to view history.

You should use the PythonBranchOperator or use two different DAG files.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow is somehow parsing every operator declared in the `__enter__` method of a subclass of `MyDAG`. From that assumption, in order not to have an operator it only suffices to declare the operator in the right place. code below:

```
class MyDAG(DAG):
    def __enter__(self, context):
         start = DummyOperator(taks_id=start)
         op = self.get_additional_operator()

         if op:
            start >> op
         else:
             end = DummyOperator(task_id=end)
             start >> end
         retrun self
     def get_additional_operator(self):
         # None if the subclass doesn't add any operator. A reference to another operator otherwise
```

The declaration of the `end` operator is made in the `else` section. I think it's only parsed when the `else` is evaluated to true.